# Convert image to bitmap

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I want to create a bitmap image of particular image but i want to resist the width and height of the bitmapimage. i am using the following code ......

```
image2  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), rid);
        Log.w("DEBUG","which is null:image i " + i.getWidth() + " OR " +i.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight () );
        Log.w("DEBUG","which is null:image h " + h.getWidth() + " OR " +h.getHeight() );
        Log.w("DEBUG","which is null:image2 " + image2.getWidth() + " OR " +image2.getHeight() );

     Bitmap image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image2, i.getWidth(), i.getHeight(), false);
        Log.w("DEBUG","which is null:image " + image.getWidth() + " OR " +image.getHeight() );
        double bmWidth = image.getWidth();
          double bmHeight = image.getHeight(); 
          if ( x < 0 || y < 0 || x > getWidth() || y > getHeight()){
               return 0; //Invalid, return 0 
              }else{
               //Convert touched x, y on View to on Bitmap
               int xBm = (int)(x * (bmWidth / getWidth()));
               int yBm = (int)(y * (bmHeight / getHeight()));
               return image.getPixel(xBm, yBm);
```

but it is not returning me the same output ........it is showing me the same width and height but my desired output is not coming. in my desired output height is get large ......so how to overcome that. can nay one suggest me

**edited :**

```
this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        // this is the important code :)  
        // Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will be null          
        this.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        this.layout(0, 0, this.getMeasuredWidth(), this.getMeasuredHeight()); 

        this.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getDrawingCache());
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        //image2  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), rid);
        Log.w("DEBUG","which is null:image i " + i.getWidth() + " OR " +i.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight () );
        Log.w("DEBUG","which is null:image h " + h.getWidth() + " OR " +h.getHeight() );
        Log.w("DEBUG","which is null:image2 " + image2.getWidth() + " OR " +image2.getHeight() );


        Log.w("DEBUG","which is null:image " + image.getWidth() + " OR " +image.getHeight() );
        double bmWidth = image.getWidth();
          double bmHeight = image.getHeight(); 
          if ( x < 0 || y < 0 || x > getWidth() || y > getHeight()){
               return 0; //Invalid, return 0 
              }else{
               //Convert touched x, y on View to on Bitmap
               int xBm = (int)(x * (bmWidth / getWidth()));
               int yBm = (int)(y * (bmHeight / getHeight()));
               return image.getPixel(xBm, yBm); 
              }
}
```

now it is showing me null pointer exception... 
**stacktrace**

```
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:358)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.example.nam.ImageIn.getmaskPixel(ImageIn.java:60)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.example.nam.AshActivity.getMaskColor(AshActivity.java:192)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.example.nam.FirstImage.pageinfo(FirstImage.java:102)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.example.nam.FirstImage.onTouch(FirstImage.java:65)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3762)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-29 15:22:07.205: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check if this is your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198291/bitmap-getwidth-returns-wrong-value

Comment: are you doing this directly inside onCreate() or in any click event?

Answer (score 4):

You could just use the imageView's image cache. It will render the entire view as it is layed out (scaled,bordered with a background etc) to a new bitmap.

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

and may be this:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715044/android-how-to-convert-whole-imageview-to-bitmap)

or form sdcard image to bitmap

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/test2.png");
BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
byte[] bMapArray= new byte[buf.available()];
buf.read(bMapArray);
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length
```

Comment: can you explain me about the sdcardimage to bitmap .....that can be help more to understand this because i am beginner

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to disable the auto-scale?

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();               
BitmapFactory.Options bfoOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
//Set to UnAutoScale
bfoOptions.inScaled = false;
//Fit to your size
matrix.setScale(widthRatio, heightRatio); 
Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resID, bfoOptions);
Bitmap outputbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, 0, tempBitmap.getWidth(), tempBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: it is showing me following error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits