# bitmap.getWidth/getHeight return different values

Tags: android, drawable

I have an icon with 48x48 dimension. And I put it under the `drawable-mdpi` folder.

Then I tried to get its size:

```
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic);
Bitmap bm = bd.getBitmap();
Log.d("render", "icon height:" + bm.getHeight());
canvas.drawBitmap(bd.getBitmap(), 0, 0, p);
```

From the logcat, it prints: `icon height: 72`.

Then I put the icon under `drawable-hdpi`, then I got: `icon height: 48`.

Then I put the icon under `drawable-ldpi`, then I got: `icon height: 96`.

What is going on?

Comment: But the icons size is 48x48, and through the android developer I should put the under the `drawable-mdpi`. Why I have to put it under the `drawable-hdpi`?

Comment: Don't take it quite so literally. Read through the answer to understand what's going on. You'll also want to read through the linked docs which you seem to not have fully absorbed quite yet. The Android Developers site certainly doesn't say to always put it in `drawable-mdpi`.

Comment: Definitely the same problem described in the other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198291/bitmap-getwidth-returns-wrong-value

Comment: OK, I will read again.

Answer (score 0):

As per [developer console](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) image size is work with different device screen density.

If you have to used  one image with all device then make **drawable folder** and put your image.

This is not good but one hack solution for simple image scale issue.