# Bitmap is returning strange Color values

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, getpixel

I am trying to transfer a standard .jpeg image into an array of Color values which are stored as int values by the Bitmap's getPixels method. My code will load in the image and send its data to a one dimensional int array, but some of the values do not make any sense when I compare them with my original image. I know the image is being read in properly because I have my program printing it to the screen. Does anyone know why my output contains such strange values?

```
        /* Test */
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.testsmall);
    image.setImageBitmap(bMap);

    int[] pixels = new int[bMap.getHeight() * bMap.getWidth()];

    bMap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight());

    int[][] colors2D = new int[bMap.getWidth()][bMap.getHeight()];
    Log.i("State", "Start");
    for (int x = 0; x < bMap.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bMap.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            colors2D[x][y] = pixels[x + y * bMap.getWidth()];
            Log.i("Inside", "X: " + x + ", Y: " + y + ", Pixel: " + pixels[x + y * bMap.getWidth()]);
        }
        Log.i("Outside", "New Line");
    }
    Log.i("State", "End");
    /* End Test */
```

*Extra Information:*

The following contains the LogCat output for this part of the program. The strange values are here. Android's Color class defines White as -1 and Black as -16777216.

http://pastebin.com/GxF4j0ef

This is the testSmall.jpg. As you can see it is quite small. Measuring only 16x16.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8hbbopoaozuu9ya/testSmall.jpg

Comment: FYI-  you normally give colors in hex.  That way you can easily break it up-  first 2 characters is transparency, next 2 is red, then green, then blue.  So white is FFFFFFFF, black is FF000000 red is FFFF0000, etc.  Much easier to compare this way.

Comment: Android expresses these hexadecimal numbers into binary when representing colors. The color class documentation here gives some examples. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

Comment: Does Android have any built in methods for converting binary numbers to hexadecimal string values?

Comment: Integer.toHexString(val);

Comment: Where ever I mention binary above, I meant integer values. I only caught this after proof-reading later.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the image was being scaled by the Android O.S. because I placed it in the drawable folder. It turns out that if you do not want a image to be scaled, you should put it in a folder named drawable-nodpi. The link below helped me figure this out.

[Bitmap getWidth returns wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198291/bitmap-getwidth-returns-wrong-value)