# getWidth() and getHeight() for Bitmap give wrong values

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a  image  captura.png in Folder

The original size is:  279 x 450 px.

But when I get width Height android returns

56*52.

```
Bitmap windowBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),  R.drawable.captura);
int width = windowBitmap.getHeight();
int height = windowBitmap.getWidth();
```

only have one image, I need the size in pixels. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you've got the file placed in a folder with different image density.

Refer to: [Bitmap getWidth returns wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198291/bitmap-getwidth-returns-wrong-value)