# How do you calculate the size of a loaded image

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I have a an image `image.png` in the drawable folder *(not any of the other drawable-hdpi, etc. folders).*

This image's size is `50x50`. But when I load it from my application like so:
    `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image)`

and then I check the size with `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, I get `150x150`.

Can anyone please explain how to calculate this `150x150` loaded size? *(Not programmatically, I just want to know if there's a formula I could have used to tell that the image would be loaded to `150x150`)*

Also, is this `150x150` in pixels?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198291/bitmap-getwidth-returns-wrong-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, the value is in pixel unit, make use of the **java doc** my friend~
- If you want the image size to stay unchanged, put it into `drawable-nodpi`
- If you put the image in the `drawable`, it is the same as in the `drawable-mdpi`, as the first Android-powered device, the T-Mobile G1 is a normal size and mdpi (medium) density :)
- And the no magic formula :

  > ldpi (low) ~120dpi
  >   mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
  >   hdpi (high) ~240dpi
  >   xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
  >   xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
  >   xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

  That is, in your case, likely developing on a xxhdpi device, 480/160*50=150, remember android is designed to be visualize all the ui elements at the same size on all screens, so the higher density , the larger scaled image .

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Drawable` image and you want to calculate the size of a loaded image

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
int h = d.getIntrinsicHeight(); 
int w = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
```

Android Documentation says:

> **public int getIntrinsicHeight ()**
>
> *Return the intrinsic height of the underlying drawable object. Returns
>   -1 if it has no intrinsic height, such as with a solid color.*
>
> **public int getIntrinsicWidth ()**
>
> *Return the intrinsic width of the underlying drawable object.Returns
>   -1 if it has no intrinsic width, such as with a solid color.*

Answer (score 0):

in android studio we use image size like this combinations.
[image]